# location: add ID to URL after update

Tags: php, mysql, url

The following updates a database record, once this is completed I would like to direct the page to view the updated record.

```
header('location:view_resource.php?Resource_ID=$id');
```

I can't seem to add the records id to the url, it comes up as: view_resource.php?Resource_ID=$id

Full code below:

```
 <?php
    include('conn.php');

    if(isset($_GET['Resource_ID']))
    {
        $id=$_GET['Resource_ID'];

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $description=$_POST['description'];
            $query3=mysql_query("UPDATE z_resource SET Name='$name', Description='$description' WHERE Resource_ID='$id'");

            if($query3)
            {
                header('location:view_resource.php?Resource_ID=$id');
            }
        }

        $query1=mysql_query("select * from z_resource where Resource_ID='$id'");
        $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
        ?>

        <form method="post" action="">
            Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $query2['Name']; ?>" /><br />
            Description:<input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $query2['Description']; ?>" /><br />

            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" />
       </form>

       <?php
   }
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your single quotes `''` into double one `""` as

```
header('location:view_resource.php?Resource_ID=$id');
       ^^                                         ^^
```

into

```
header("location:view_resource.php?Resource_ID=$id");
       ^^                                         ^^
```